# Logging hibernate query not working

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, logback

I want lo log hibernate generated sql queries using logback logging framework, but problem is that it is generating log file but not logging anything related to hibernate.

This is how logback.xml looks like

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${Project_HOME}\\module\\logs\\module.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <rollingPolicy     class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${Project_HOME}\\module\\logs\\module_%d{yyyy-    MM-dd}.%i.log.zip
            </fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10KB</maxFileSize>

            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %-5level [%file:%line] - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
<logger name="org.hibernate.SQL">
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>
```

Also all other logging using same appender is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to add a property in hibernate-cfg.xml

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

Hope this will help you .

Comment: Show_sql will always log to System.out()

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you change your logger config a little:

```
    <logger name="org.hibernate">
        <level value="info"/>
    </logger>
```

Comment: @jaishukla: It should work, specially if it works for your other classes. Could you please upload a part of the log file?

Comment: @jaishukla: are you sure that you're calling hibernate from your code?